# Using Multiple Regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to write a regular expression that will evaluate the following conditions:

- 2 consecutive lower case characters
- at least 1 digit
- at least 1 upper case character
- 2 consecutive identical punctuation characters

For example, the string 'aa1A!!' should match, as should '!!A1aa'.

I have written the following  regular expression:

```
'/(?=([a-z]){2,})(?=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])(?=(\W)\1)/'
```

I have found each individual expression works, but I am struggling to put it all together. What am I missing?

Comment: No. Just use 4 regexes. There's no reason to re-engineer it into a monster.

Comment: Give an example of a string that it should match.

Comment: I agree with Laurel, make 4 regexes. Your second example does not start with 2 lower case letters!

Comment: Ok, but IF I needed to write one expression, how would I do it? Also, it is not important where the 2 lower case letters are, so long as they are consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your pattern must be anchored to be sure that lookaheads are only tested from the position at the start of string. Then, since your characters can be everywhere in the string, you need to start the subpatterns inside lookahead with `.*`.

`\W` is a character class for non-word characters (all that is not `[A-Za-z0-9_]` that includes spaces, control characters, accented letters...). IMO, `\pP` or `[[:punct:]]` are more appropriate.

```
/^(?=.*[a-z]{2})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*(\pP)\1)/
```

About the idea to make 4 patterns instead of 1, it looks like a good idea, it tastes like a good idea, but it's useless and slower. However, it can be interesting if you want to know what particular rule fails.

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfectly informative and helpfully suggestive.